# Flutter UncontrolledProviderScope error with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

Here i have a simple animated dialog which with that i can show one screen into that. this screen into animated dialog sending request on appearing into dialog and can be receive data from server without any problem. but when i drag this dialog on top of screen to get full width and height i get this error:

```
This UncontrolledProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
```

in fact i think this screen send multiple request when appear into dialog and when its shows as a new screen instance

problem is

```dart
ref.read(profileProvider.notifier).send(
        method: HTTP.POST,
        endPoint: Server.$userProfile,
        parameters: {
          'uuid': '123',
        },
      );
```

into `MyProfile` class

**Full source code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:my_app/core/service/server.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

import 'core/service/repository/request_repository.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(child: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends HookConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () {
              showGeneralDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: true,
                barrierLabel: "hi",
                // barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                // transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                pageBuilder: (context, pAnim, sAnim) {
                  return const SafeArea(
                      child: FloatingDialog(
                        previewType: PreviewDialogsType.profile,
                      ));
                },
                transitionBuilder: (context, pAnim, sAnim, child) {
                  if (pAnim.status == AnimationStatus.reverse) {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.0).animate(pAnim),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: pAnim,
                      child: child,
                    );
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50.0,
              color: Colors.indigoAccent,
              child: const Text('LongPress please'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum PreviewDialogsType {
  profile,
}

class FloatingDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final PreviewDialogsType previewType;

  const FloatingDialog({super.key, required this.previewType});

  @override
  _FloatingDialogState createState() => _FloatingDialogState();
}

class _FloatingDialogState extends State<FloatingDialog> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late double _dragStartYPosition;
  late double _dialogYOffset;

  late AnimationController _returnBackController;
  late Animation<double> _dialogAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dialogYOffset = 0.0;
    _returnBackController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1300))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _dialogYOffset = _dialogAnimation.value;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _returnBackController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget myContents = PreviewDialog(
      type: widget.previewType,
    );

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 100.0,
        bottom: 10.0,
        left: 16.0,
        right: 16.0,
      ),
      child: Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0.0, _dialogYOffset),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onVerticalDragStart: (dragStartDetails) {
                  _dragStartYPosition = dragStartDetails.globalPosition.dy;
                },
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (dragUpdateDetails) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dialogYOffset = (dragUpdateDetails.globalPosition.dy) - _dragStartYPosition;
                  });
                  if (_dialogYOffset < -130) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                          pageBuilder: (context, pAnim, sAnim) => myContents,
                          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          transitionsBuilder: (context, pAnim, sAnim, child) {
                            if (pAnim.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
                              return ScaleTransition(
                                scale: Tween(begin: 0.8, end: 1.0)
                                    .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: pAnim, curve: Curves.elasticOut)),
                                child: child,
                              );
                            } else {
                              return child;
                            }
                          }),
                    );
                  }
                },
                onVerticalDragEnd: (dragEndDetails) {
                  _dialogAnimation = Tween(begin: _dialogYOffset, end: 0.0)
                      .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _returnBackController, curve: Curves.elasticOut));
                  _returnBackController.forward(from: _dialogYOffset);

                  _returnBackController.forward(from: 0.0);
                },
                child: myContents,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PreviewDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final PreviewDialogsType type;
  final String? uuid;

  const PreviewDialog({Key? key, required this.type, this.uuid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PreviewDialog> createState() => _PreviewDialogState();
}

class _PreviewDialogState extends State<PreviewDialog> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: MyProfile(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyProfile extends HookConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    useEffect(() {
      ref.read(profileProvider.notifier).send(
        method: HTTP.POST,
        endPoint: Server.$userProfile,
        parameters: {
          'uuid': '123',
        },
      );
      return () {};
    }, []);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height:double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ref.watch(profileProvider).when(
                idle: () => const SizedBox(),
                loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                success: (success) {
                  return const Text('successful');
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) {
                  return Text('error');
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get an error. `hooks_riverpod: ^2.0.2`, tested in browser, changed the `profileProvider` to `final profileProvider = FutureProvider<void>((ref) => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)));`. With different use cases, the data was loaded and no error occurred. Is there a minimum reproducible code to repeat the error?

Comment: I think I was able to catch it after all))

Comment: you change the state inside `ref.read(profileProvider.notifier).send()`?